# Vue 3, Bootstrap 5 cannot reading properties of undefined 'backdrop'

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-5, vite, bootstrap5-modal

I am trying to use Vue3 (Vite) and Bootstrap 5 to create a modal that is called by code. However, when opening the modal from its parent, an error is thrown.

I have bootstrap installed and included:

`import bootstrap` (main.js)

`import bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap` does not change anything.

I have created a simple modal that listens for a prop and then opens the modal.

When I open it, the error appears:
`Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'backdrop')`

```
<template>
    <div class="modal" tabindex="-1" id="errModal" aria-labelledby="ErrorModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title">Error {{ this.occurred }}</h5>
                    <button type="button" class="btn-close" data-bs-dismiss="modal"
                        aria-label="ErrorModalLabel"></button>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                    <p>{{ this.error_message }}</p>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-bs-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import { Modal } from "bootstrap"
export default {
    props: {
        occurred: String,
        error_message: String,
        show: Boolean,
    },
    components: {
        myModal: null
    },
    data() {
        return {
        }
    },
    methods: {
    },
    mounted() {
        this.myModal = new Modal(document.getElementById('errModal'))
    },
    watch: {
        show: function (newVal, oldVal) { // watch it
            this.cam_prop = newVal.properties
        },
    }
};
</script>
```

Calling from Parent:

```
<RegIdentErrorModalVue id="#ErrModal" :show="this.error" :occurred="'Identification'" :error_message="this.error_text">
        </RegIdentErrorModalVue>
```

Creating the Modal with `new bootstrap.Modal` does not work (bootstrap not defined)

I think the error is importing, but the styling works, could it be Vite?

Comment: import your library on your component

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to initialize the modal before the DOM is ready.
I suggest you initialize the component  at the mounted of the parent component. Something like this:

```
   Parent Component
<template>
    ...
    <RegIdentErrorModalVue v-if="isMountedComponent" id="#ErrModal" :show="this.error" :occurred="'Identification'" :error_message="this.error_text" />
    ...
</template>

<script>
export default {
    data() {
        return {
            isMountedComponent: false,
        }
    },
    mounted() {
        this.isMountedComponent = true;
    },
}
</script>
```